# A proof of Mathias theorem about characteristic functions

Tags: probability, reference-request, characteristic-functions, hermite-polynomials

I am looking for a proof of Mathias theorem, as described [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Criteria_for_characteristic_functions) and possible applications of it. (Polya's theorem has a nice consequence per example, it allows to show that if $X_1+X=^dX_2+X$ we may not have  $X_1=^dX_2$).

The theorem states that:

A real-valued, even, continuous, absolutely integrable function φ, with φ(0) = 1, is a characteristic function if and only if
:

$(-1)^n \left ( \int_{\mathbf{R}} \varphi(pt)e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}H_{2n}(t)dt \right ) \geq 0$
for $n = 0,1,2,…$, and all $p > 0$. Here $H_{2n}$ denotes the Hermite polynomial of degree $2n$.